# How to find Bottom-left and Top-right latitude and longitude from given latitude and longitude?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I want to convert given latitude and longitude as per below:-

1. Bottom-left latitude
2. Bottom-left longitude
3. Top-right latitude
4. Top-right longitude

For example, I have a Latitude:29.0167 and Longitude:77.3833. Now How I can convert these co-ordinate to Bottom-left latitude,Bottom-left longitude,Top-right latitude and Top-right longitude.

Please can any one help me.

Comment: Relative to what, exactly?

Comment: I have one api, where I need to pass 4 co-ordinate. Link : http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/37,-105,45,-94? i.e. 37,-105,45,-94. So How I can find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the distance between your two points.  If the distance is small (say around 100 km), then you can usually use a flat earth approximation.  For longer distances, you need to use the 'great circle' distance.  AKA Haversine formula.  This distance you computed is the diagonal distance of the square.  See this site for all the formulas you need: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Compute the bearing from bottom-left to top-right.  Again, see site above for computing bearing between two lat/lon points.

To get the bottom-right, you know the distance of the side of your box is the diagonal distance divided by the square root of 2.  This is from right triangle geometry:  x^2 + x^2 = hypotenuse.

From the bearing computed above, add 45 degrees.  You now have a range (D/sqrt(2)) and a bearing to the bottom-right point.  Use the site above to compute the lat/lon from a lat/lon with a range and bearing.

Repeat for the top-left by subtracting 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if I understand what you are trying to do, but if i do you can just use Math.Floor and Math.Ceiling. They give you the first integer smaller, respective greater the provided number.

```
float lon =77.38;
float lat = 29.01;
float loLat=Math.Floor(lat); //29
float upLat=Math.Ceiling(lat); //30
float loLon=Math.Floor(lat); //77
float upLon=Math.Ceiling(lat); //78
```

You can then calculate your desired corners from this.

Comment: Can you specify why exactly it will not solve it. I am still unsure what exactly your are trying to get. Maybe provide a crafted example of input and desired output.